# Are soldiers affected by area effects (smoke grenades, poison clouds) as they run through them?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I know that smoke grenades affect soldiers' defense when they stand in the area while being shot at by the enemy during the enemy's turn, and are affected by thin men poison clouds if they stand in the area.

However, do smoke grenades or poison clouds affect soldiers in the middle of a move or turn? e.g., if I wish to run a soldier from point A through point B and finish on point C, and I suspect that he will trigger an alien overwatch as he runs through point B, will a smoke grenade on point B protect him? If a soldier runs through a poison cloud but does not start or end the turn in the cloud, will he become poisoned?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, moving through AOE does affect you as would standing in it. This is especially annoying with poison clouds, because the pathfinder code *won't* route around them automatically, and trying to do it manually uses up a move point.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the path finding, willingly running through a cloud that just killed one of your squad mates makes me think of lemmings

Comment: @pixel But it's the *closest path!* God, stupid commanding offi.../dies

Comment: Yep, while the 2-tempo movement greatly simplifies the original game's click-spend(unknown amount of until performed)-time units approach while retaining pretty much all of its flexibility, the fact that they don't let you place way points (via shift holding or something), when you want to add more detail to a movement inside the action radius is pretty sucky. That's how I made my first TBS game and I always thought it was corner-cutting corny.

Comment: The pathfinder really should be smart enough to route you around the poison unless the ONLY path is through it. Even then you should have some kind of indicator (like say a flashing poison tag) to inform you so you can still choose to do it if you really need to make the move.